# Retrieve json data. but having this error - "Trying to get property of non object"

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I'm still a newbie in laravel.

I have this result in JSON and I want to get the 'bio' inside the 'user_details'.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jasper Mendiola",
    "username": "jasperduane77",
    "created_at": "2017-07-22 10:11:04",
    "updated_at": "2017-07-22 10:11:04",
    "userType": "Administrator",
    "user_details": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "profile_pic": null,
        "bio": "frustrated software blahblahblah"
    }
```

I tried this code in my view

```
{{$user->user_details->bio}}
```

but Im having the error

**>     Trying to get property of non-object**

This is my laravel Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\UserDetail;
use DB;

class UsersController extends Controller
{

    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        $user = User::with('userDetails')->find($user_id);

        /**** When I enter this code, I get the error
        return view('profile.index')->with('user', $user); */

        return json_encode($user);
    }
}
```

How do you exactly do this? Help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please check my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45581245/5013099

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use like this:

```
<?php
$jsonData = '{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Jasper Mendiola",
    "username": "jasperduane77",
    "created_at": "2017-07-22 10:11:04",
    "updated_at": "2017-07-22 10:11:04",
    "userType": "Administrator",
    "user_details": {
        "user_id": 1,
        "profile_pic": null,
        "bio": "frustrated software blahblahblah"
    }
}';
$josnObj = json_decode($jsonData); 
echo $josnObj->user_details->bio;//frustrated software blahblahblah
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**If you want to send JSON response**

In your controller, just replace **return json_encode($user);**  with **return $user;**

It will automatically send $user as json response. If you will use **return json_encode($user);** it will just send json response in string format and you will need to convert this string into array or object using json_decode() in your view.

**If you want to send data to view**

then in your controller:

```
return view('profile.index', ['user' => $user]);
```

Then in your view:

```
{{$user->user_details->bio}}
```

Comment: Also works. I just have to add this $user = json_decode($user); before passing it to the view function.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning a json string so that would be cool for an API request. The way laravel does this is using the view() so we can render a blade template. In that case you should do something like this:

Controller code:

```
return view('users.index', [ 'user' => $user ]);
```

In here you would need a blade file inside of views/users/index.blade.php and in there you can call the {{$user->user_details->bio}} because you're still using the User model instead of a json "string".

Comment: The error will still be there. You should decode the json object first before you can pass it to the view function.

Comment: @jDmendiola, are the user_details defined as a key->value array? in that case you can use {{ $user->user_details['bio'] }}. The encoding/decoding of the model doesn't feel right